# Is it possible to update / add to a numpy histogram (specifically, numpy.histogram2d) that is already populated?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have already populated a numpy.histogram2d with a pair of lists `(x0,y0)`. Can I now augment the histogram with an additional pair of two lists `(x1,y1)` so that the histogram contains both `(x0,y0)` and `(x1,y1)`?

The relevant and official documentation is here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html
On this page I only see parameters and returns, but not functions that this object supports. How can I find all the supported functions?

Comment: `histogram2d` isn't an object as such (except in the sense that everything in Python is an object); it's a function that returns a tuple of three `ndarray`s. I can't tell what you mean by "functions that this object supports". Maybe you could show some more of your code to make it clearer what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have a class member variable that is a np.histogram2d() and there is an update function that wants to augment this member during runtime. This function gets called quite often. I'll just maintain two lists in that case.

Comment: Nevermind, I realize now that I can just maintain the first ndarray that is returned by the histogram function (based on jotasi's response).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`np.histogram2D`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) is not an object as pointed out in the comments. It is a function that returns an array with bin values as well as two for the bin edges. Nonetheless, as long as you do not compute a normed histogram, you can simply add to the histogram with the same bins. For example, to extend the example from the [`np.histogram2d` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(3, 1, 100)
y = np.random.normal(1, 1, 100)

xedges = [0, 1, 1.5, 3, 5]
yedges = [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xedges, yedges))

x2 = np.random.normal(3, 1, 100)
y2 = np.random.normal(1, 1, 100)

H += np.histogram2d(x2, y2, bins=(xedges, yedges))[0]
```

This will give you the added combined bin values in `H` with bin edges `xedges` and `yedges`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a bit of self-promotion, if you want to use updateable histograms and object-like histogram behaviour in general, you can try a library that I wrote, https://github.com/janpipek/physt.